# How do I get user device IDs from Auth0?

Tags: authentication, auth0

Currently using Auth0 for my application. In Auth0 we are storing the device_ids passed when a user logs in. Using an Auth0 rule, I am currently storing the user_id and other information in a DynamoDB table. I would like to include an array of the devices associated with a user. I have been unable to find how to access that data in the Auth0 docs. Anyone aware of how to do this?